# How can I set database failover portal with Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli, compose-db

I am using sequelize to connect to a postgres db which is hosted on compose.io.

```
const db = new Sequelize(DATABASE_URL, {
  logging: false,
  pool: {
    max: 15,
    min: 1,
    idle: 10000,
    acquire: 10000,
  },
});
```

How can I set a failover portal?

```
postgres://[username]:[password]@gcp-us-east1-cpu.2.dblayer.com:16070/compose
postgres://[username]:[password]@gcp-us-east1-cpu.0.dblayer.com:16070/compose
```

Comment: Have you tried setting up read replicas in the connection configuration? See https://sequelize.org/master/manual/read-replication.html for details, but it should just involve changing your `DATABASE_URL` to just the database, and adding hosts for each server in the `replication:` configuration key...

Comment: This is only for read, right?

Comment: Yes it’s for handling replicas. What kind of redundancy are you using? If you’re doing failover clustering,your cluster OS should be providing a virtual IP address; in this case make sure you’re connecting to that address and it should failover without any involvement from Sequelize (other than reconnecting the dropped connections, which should happen automatically after timeout).

Comment: The other way to accomplish failover is by using a connection pooler such as pgbouncer. Basically, Sequelize connects to the pooler, which proxies the connection to the current failover master.